# find records in a third table based on where unmatched columns in two tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get records like below, but could not:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM D
  WHERE D.C IN (
      SELECT A.*
      FROM A
      LEFT JOIN B ON (A.C = B.C)
      WHERE B.C IS NULL)
```

Basically want to get whatever is **not-matched** in the **compare** of `A.Column` & `B.Column` for a select in `D` based on the `A & B` result.

> **Edited to show code sample in the real application:**

This is the sample code in the php used for sending renewals notification to expiring users and logging to two tables mailer & renewals based on expiring users:

```
      SELECT * FROM expiring_users WHERE expiring_users.id IN(
           SELECT mailer_log.*
           FROM mailer_log
           LEFT JOIN renewals_log ON (mailer_log.id = renewals_log.id)
           WHERE renewals_log.id IS NULL)
```

Hope this hepls in undesrtanding the situation.

Comment: but what is the column in `A` or `B`  that you want to match to `D.C`?

Comment: I  think you should post some sample data and your expected result, that will be more helpful for us to understand your question.

Comment: @All, This is the part of my code where I do the select: `SELECT * FROM expiring_users WHERE expiring_users.id IN(
SELECT mailer_log.*
FROM mailer_log
    LEFT JOIN renewals_log ON (mailer_log.id = renewals_log.id)
WHERE renewals_log.id IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. For others in this situation, I used the code below:

```
SELECT * FROM expiring_users 
WHERE expiring_users.id IN(
    SELECT mailer_log.id
    FROM mailer_log
    LEFT JOIN renewals_log ON (mailer_log.id = renewals_log.id)
    WHERE renewals_log.id IS NULL)
```

It gets all records from the `expiring_users` table based on the **not-matched** entries in the `mailer_log` and `renewals_log`.

This is used to verify if the notification mailer system failed to update records in the renewals and expiring users based on the existing users table.